# How to get value from string php

Tags: php, magento

how can i get value from $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()?
With a print_r I have this return:

```
[credit_card_token] => 849832748932uhdfhsiufhi [credit_card_owner] => NoNoNoNo [installment_quantity] => 2 [installment_value] => 98.11 ) ); etc
```

I need the value from installment_quantity and installment_value

thank you

Answer (score 2):

That method is returning the array you need, so simply assign it to a variable and access the items you need:

```
$data = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance();

$quantity = $data['installment_quantity'];
$value = $data['installment_value'];
```

Answer (score 1):

this "`$order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()`" returns array, so you need to assign this to a variable and get values by using keys.

```
$credit_card_info=$order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance();
```

**Now you can get values by using keys.**

```
$credit_card_token=$credit_card_info['credit_card_token'];
$credit_card_owner=$credit_card_info['credit_card_owner'];
```